# Spring Data MongoDB how do I set auto-connect-retry="true" with javaconfig style?

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb

Spring Data MongoDB how do I set auto-connect-retry="true"  with javaconfig style?

below is my config class can someone please let me know? what I want is if its running and one of the nodes go down I would like it to auto=connect to the new node

```
@Configuration
@EnableMongoRepositories
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = {MongoDBApp.class})
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class MongoConfiguration extends AbstractMongoConfiguration {


    @Override
    protected String getDatabaseName() {
        return "demo";
    }



    @Override
    public Mongo mongo() throws Exception {
        /**
         *
         * this is for a single db
         */

        Mongo m = new Mongo();
        m.setOptions();
        // return new Mongo();


        /**
         *
         * This is for a relset of db's
         */

        return new Mongo(new ArrayList<ServerAddress>() {{ add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27017)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27027)); add(new ServerAddress("127.0.0.1", 27037)); }});

    }

    @Override
    protected String getMappingBasePackage() {
        return "com.xxx.mongodb.example.domain";
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply do the following:

```
Mongo mongo = new Mongo();
mongo.getMongoOptions().setAutoConnectRetry(true);
```

Generally speaking, the `MongoOptions` type exposed contains all the settings you can apply through the namespace.